# Manage several files in PHP

Tags: php

I'm testing php because I'm a freshman in this matter. I put my php code in a free server, they let me do my own index.php, manage some php variables (like register_globals, magic_quotes_gpc etc. I left them as default), but apparently I can handle not more than one file in a php code, for example:

```
<?php

//--------Updating Data-------------
$cdc = intval($_POST['cantidadDeCapitulos']);
$toWrite = array('ctot' => $cdc);
for($i=1;$i<$cdc+1;$i += 1){
   $toWrite["cap".$i] = $_POST['numdeCap'.$i];
}//---------------------------------

$datos = file_get_contents("myfile.json.");

$toWrite = json_encode( $toWrite );

//Open a file in write mode

$fp = fopen("myfile2.json", "w");

if(fwrite($fp, "$toWrite")) { 
  echo "&verify=success&"; 
} else { 
  echo "&verify=fail&"; 
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

If I comment out the line `$datos = file_get_contents("myfile.json.");` it's alright!, something is written in myfile2.json but if it is uncommented, the data is not updated. Both files have permission 666 and they are in the same directory i.e., /root.

Comment: Try 777 in stead of 666.

Comment: @RobinJ 666 will still allow writing.

Comment: @SomeKittens I know, but I thought you might need execution permissions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$datos = file_get_contents("myfile.json.");
```

Seems like a typo has occurred. Take off the final dot from your file. I mean, change the line to:

```
$datos = file_get_contents("myfile.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$file = 'myfile.json';
// Open the file to get existing content

$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```